# Eigenvalues of Blockmatrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a Blockmatrix of the form

$
M = \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
A & B \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$
$A$ and $B$ are not nessecarily squared, though.
Can I conclude that the matrix M has the eigenvalues of both, $A$ and $B$?
Where can I find a proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix, how can it be an Eiganvalue?

Comment: I wrote the eigenvalues OF $A$ and 1 (from $I$).
This is in contrast to "the eigenvalues ___ $A$ and 1".
So, A has some eigenvalues...

Comment: Just realized, that B is not I, as it is not nessecarily squared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true. Let $\lambda$ be an Eiganvalue of A and let $a$ be an Eiganvector of $A$. Let $x=(a,0)$. Then computing the multiplication gives $Mx=\lambda x$ as desired, and we can obtain the same result for $B$ by using $y=(0,b)$ where $b$ is the Eiganvector for $\lambda$ with respect to $B$

Comment: Gosh, thank you! I could hit my head against my table, for not seeing this obvious fact. I should start thinking instead of spending the day, searching for answers, no one would write down, for their obviousness.

Comment: NB: all your assumptions about $A$ and $B$ are not necessary for this proof to work, as the fact is true of every matrix of the form that M has

Comment: Yeah, I can see that now. I was just so blocked, that I wanted to be as specific as possible, to make sure, that it does not fail due to over-generality.
I will remove the assumptions about $A$ and $B$ in the question now, so in case, someone who might have the same question some day, won't be foold by my assumptions.